# How to plot a graph in lattice based on columns

Tags: r, lattice

I have a data frame like this:

```
epochs   lm      le    kd
-------|-------|------|----
1      | 0.38  | 0.25 | 0.21
2      | 0.34  | 0.22 | 0.44
3      | 0.45  | 0.33 | 0.22
```

I would like to plot this graph using `xyplot` in `lattice` with interaction of `lm`,`le`,and, `kd`. X-axis would be `epochs` and Y-axis would have a range from 0.10 to 0.60 (depending on the data)

I tried below but its not working because I don't know what to put in Y axis?

> xyplot(epochs ~ 'whattoputhere??', data=data,
>   +        groups = paste("Le =", le, "lm =", lm, "kd = ", kd),
>   +        type = "l",
>   +        auto.key =
>   +            list(space = "right", points = FALSE, lines = TRUE))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally lattice functions will be much easier to use with "long data" and yours is unfortunately "wide". The `melt` function was a great gift to R users (thank you, Hadley).

```
> dat <- read.table(text="epochs |  lm   |   le  |  kd
+ 1      | 0.38  | 0.25 | 0.21
+ 2      | 0.34  | 0.22 | 0.44
+ 3      | 0.45  | 0.33 | 0.22", header=TRUE,sep="|")
> require(reshape2)
Loading required package: reshape2

> datm <- melt(dat, id.var="epochs")
> str(datm)
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ epochs  : num  1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
 $ variable: Factor w/ 3 levels "lm","le","kd": 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
 $ value   : num  0.38 0.34 0.45 0.25 0.22 0.33 0.21 0.44 0.22

xyplot(value ~ epochs, groups=variable, datm, type="b",  
         auto.key =  list( space="right", points = FALSE, lines = TRUE) )
```

[image]